# How much do you have in savings (GBP)? UK Visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I put the balance confirmation of my two savings account plus the amount in the fixed deposit account. Will it be an issue?

Comment: Why would it be an issue? Assuming you have statements/paperwork to prove it and can demonstrate the source of the funds